# set timezone for tomcat

Tags: timezone, tomcat7, openshift

I've got issue with this file `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_start`, the text is `export JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Stockholm"` but new timezone does't work. It's not changing.

Any help, with this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you definitely need to change the system default time zone? I generally find it's better to just avoid ever using it - you end up with clearer code that way.

Comment: It's easier 'cause It will be used only in specific country. So I need to change it.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very convincing argument to me...

Comment: To echo on Jon's point - it's a "best practice" to never rely on the time zone setting of a server or application host environment running on a server.  Server-based applications should be developed to take only the UTC time from the server, and deal with time zone conversions within the application itself.   Local-to-the-machine time zone settings should be reserved for desktop and mobile applications only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the "rhc env set" command to set the JAVA_OPTS_EXT environment variable like this:

```
rhc env-set JAVA_OPTS_EXT="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Stockholm" --app <appname>
```

But I ultimately agree with Jon that you should avoid using that timezone at all.

Comment: thanx, I've problem finding resolution in documentation:)
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#java-variables